# How to hide each document on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I am trying to hide each and every element of document when window is resized to some pixels.

This is what i tried to script-

When window is resized to some pixels then each document goes hidden else shown.

I tried implementing this script-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var eachdoc=$(document).each();
            var docsize = eachdoc.width();
            $(window).resize(function () {
                $(document).each(function () {
                    if (docsize > $(window).width()-400) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Well this script is not working, How can i improve this script to hide each element on window resize?
Please suggest !

Comment: are there multiple documents in the page? do you want to hide some elements / document

Comment: Using an each in a window resize = hard for the CPU

Comment: @ArunPJohny, yes some tables and blocks of imformation.

Comment: look up media queries in css

Comment: those are not documents, AFAIK one window will have a single document (w/o frames/iframes)

Comment: By the way `$('*')` <- Select all tag in the document.

Comment: @SethMcClaine, any jQuery script may help?

Comment: probably you need to share the html as well and the list of elements that need to be hidden/shown

Comment: $('body').hide(); ---More context might help, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, there are multiple elements in HTML, i just wanted to know if this is possible with jQuery or not? if yes then how?

Comment: @Manoz, Almost everything is possible, but we don't know what you want to do. Without that information, we can't give you the best answer possible...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, Thankyou for your interest, i am trying to hide each document element on body when window is resized to some pixels. Hope you got information.

Comment: @Manoz, still unclear to me, you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/YLU6n/2/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, yeah sort of, That helped me little bit. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The basic implementation could be something like

```
$(function () {
    var els=$('.mytable, .mypara');//list of elements
    var docsize = eachdoc.width();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var cuttoff = $(window).width() - 400;
        els.each(function (idx, el) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.width() > cuttoff) {
                $this.hide();
            } else {
                $this.show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this is the best solution or even a good solution, so somebody correct me as needed.. but I'm thinking this way will be a little easier on your cpu.

```
$.fn.filterNumberRange = function(item, low, high){
  return this.filter(function(){
      var value = +$(this).attr(item);
      return value >= low && value <= high;
  });
};

var documents = $('document-selector');

$(documents).each(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-width', $(this).width());
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  var current-width = parseInt($(window).width()) - 400;

  $(documents).filterNumberRange( 'data-width', 0, current-width ).show;
  $(documents).filterNumberRange( 'data-width', current-width + 1, 9999 ).hide;
});
```

Grabbed the filtering function from here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/new-attribute-selectors-for-less-than-and-greater-than